# Проблема с парсером grok

Tags: elasticsearch

Добрый день, проблема с парсингом строчки лога.
Есть строка, к примеру:

> 2017-02-17 09:18:15.144043 x.x.x.x x.x.x.x IN x.x.x.x. A x.x.x.x 3600
>   1

```
фильтр:    
    input {
    syslog {
    port => 5110
    type => dns_requests
    }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "dns_requests" {
    grok {
      patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns"]
      match => { "message" => "{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{TIME:time} %{IP:client} %{IP:dns_server} %{WORD:class} %{WORD:query} %{WORD:type} %{WORD:answer} %{NUMBER:ttl} %{NUMBER:count}" }
      remove_field => ["message"]
    }
  }
}
```

Лог не парсится, приходит в изначальном виде, в каждой записи Kibana **tags _grokparsefailure**
Версия logstash и elasticsearch 2.3.1

Comment: Приведите пару-тройку реальных строк из логов.

Answer (score 0):

При условии, что вы верно определяете `TYPE` ваших сообщений, для строки

```
2017-02-17 09:18:15.144043 10.220.1.1 8.8.8.8 IN host.dom. A 127.0.0.1 3600 1
```

подойдет такой grok:

```
%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{TIME:time} %{IPV4:client} %{IPV4:dns_server} %{WORD:class} %{DATA:query} %{WORD:type} %{DATA:answer} %{INT:ttl} %{INT:count}
```

Тестировать гроки можно [тут](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/), а изучить доступные шаблоны [здесь](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns#) или [здесь](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)